# Book that I read long ago. I believe that the word "chaos" is in the title

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the book, bombs that had traveled from another galaxy were causing great damage to human planets. Ultimately, the main character makes a journey to the other galaxy and finds the ruins of the civilization that launched the bombs.

It turns out that the aliens were able to catch a glimpse of a future in which we are walking around in the ruins of their civilization and they assume that we destroy them. So they sent out the bombs in the hope of eliminating that future, but it was their bombs that eventually caused us to visit their galaxy and we had nothing to do with the collapse of their civilization.

Comment: One of these, possibly; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=chaos&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: Not what you are looking for, but you may be interested in another series called "[Chronicle of the Dark Star](https://www.goodreads.com/series/179730-chronicle-of-the-dark-star)", which is about humankind being forced to flee the solar system because their sun is mysteriously starting to go nova, and they fire bombs at a system that they determine is habitable, but those bombs nearly wipe out an alien civilization, whose survivors vow revenge. They attempt to destroy all the fleeing human ships, but fail due to the protagonists figuring out how to use a time-travel device.

Comment: The ending is a spoiler, so I won't reveal it, but it has a similar flavour to yours.

Comment: Note OP confirmation comment below and that proposed duplicate target is already the target of another question closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 26):

I'll throw out a possibility here. What about "[Patterns of Chaos](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2037247.Patterns_Of_Chaos)" by Colin Kapp? Published in 1972, the story involves human planets being bombarded by "hellburner" nuclear missiles launched millions of years ago from the Andromeda galaxy, with the aim of killing the protagonist, Bron. It somehow involves prediction of the future using chaos theory, but I do not remember how well it accords with the rest of the question.

The OP has accepted this answer, and I have now found a nice [review](https://mporcius.blogspot.com/2016/05/patterns-of-chaos-by-colin-kapp.html) of the book which also confirms the main plot points given in the question.

Comment: Certainly sounds like it!

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Phoenix remember to select the green checkmark since it is the answer you want.

Comment: @KingLogic Just the checkmark, it doesn't show as green before it's selected (even on rollover).

Comment: "Chaos theory" as a mathematical discipline only existed under that name since 1975 with "Period 3 implies Chaos" (Yorke's provocatively titled paper) and only really entered the public imagination in 1987 with "Chaos, making of a new science".  In 1972 "Chaos" would not have had the associations with the butterfly effect.